# Neo4j via Blueprints getting stuck when used from different threads

Tags: neo4j, deadlock, tinkerpop

I'm using blueprints-neo4j-graph-2.5.0 from maven repositories.

While using the graph from different threads, neo4j freezes. The code that recreates the problem, and the call stack is attached. Any resolutions around this, or any usage patterns would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class Simplest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Simplest();
    }

    Graph g = new Neo4jGraph("E:/temp/neoTest");
    Vertex a = g.addVertex(null);

    public Simplest() { 
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Vertex b = g.addVertex(null);
                a.addEdge("relation", b);
                System.out.println("never reaches here...");
            }
        }).start();
    }

}
```

Stack trace follows...

```
Thread [Thread-2] (Suspended)   
    waiting for: RWLock  (id=43)    
    Object.wait(long) line: not available [native method]   
    RWLock(Object).wait() line: 503 
    RWLock.deadlockGuardedWait(Transaction, RWLock$TxLockElement, LockType) line: 652   
    RWLock.acquireWriteLock(Transaction) line: 344  
    LockManagerImpl.getWriteLock(Object, Transaction) line: 84  
    LockManagerImpl.getWriteLock(Object) line: 77   
    WritableTransactionState.acquireWriteLock(Object) line: 269 
    LockType$2.acquire(TransactionState, Object) line: 51   
    NodeManager.getNodeForProxy(long, LockType) line: 473   
    InternalAbstractGraphDatabase$8.lookup(long, LockType) line: 791    
    NodeProxy.createRelationshipTo(Node, RelationshipType) line: 207    
    Neo4jGraph.addEdge(Object, Vertex, Vertex, String) line: 487    
    Neo4jVertex.addEdge(String, Vertex) line: 47    
    Simplest$1.run() line: 24   
    Thread.run() line: not available
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blueprints seems to associate the current transaction to the current thread. So it has to be closed before using the graph from another thread. TransactionalGraph.commit() closes the present transaction. The following works.

```
public class Simplest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Simplest();
    }

    Neo4jGraph g;
    Vertex a;

    {
        g = new Neo4jGraph("E:/temp/neoTest");
        a = g.addVertex(null);
        g.commit();
    }

    public Simplest() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Vertex b = g.addVertex(null);
                a.addEdge("relation", b);
                g.commit();
                System.out.println("now reaches here...");
            }
        }).start();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use explicit transaction management and not rely on the implicit transaction handling in blueprints. Best to disable auto-transactions any only manage them manually via `neo4jGraph.beginTransaction()` or what that function was called.